# Array to Set not cuts off java array

Tags: java, arrays, hashset

I am converting an arraylist to a set in java and the resulting set is not producing the expected results.

```
    String[] characterName = {"C","A","P","T","A","I","N","A","M","E","R","I","C","A"};
    String[] alphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
    List<String> pool = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<characterName.length;i++) {
        pool.add(characterName[i]);
    }

    int difference = 19-characterName.length;

    for(int i=0;i<difference;i++) {
        pool.add(alphabet[i]);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(pool);
    Set<String> poolSet= new HashSet<>();
    poolSet.addAll(pool);
```

I have debugged this but when I addAll from pool to the hashset, it only adds the first 11 characters of the array. EVEN though when I debug, it says pool = 19, it only adds 11. Am I calling this wrong? It seems so simple, but it's not adding all. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sets can't have duplicates by their definition. When you add a duplicate element it will just disappear.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `difference` variable?

Comment: That makes total sense. Difference determines how many additional letters I need to add to the pool in order to get to 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set`s in java either contain an item or they don't. They don't contain multiple copies of it.

In your example, out of `CAPTAINAMERICAABCDE`, there is only 11 unique characters, `CAPTINMERBD`. That's why you end up with 11 in the end.

You will likely want to use a `List` instead, as that would allow multiple instances of the same thing.